# JQuery val() throws runtime error when setting form value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, forms

I'm new to Javascript/JQuery, so apologies if I'm missing something simple.  I'm trying to make a button to calculate the total from a quantity & unit price, and populate the total field with the result.  This is done in ASP.NET MVC3, using VS2010.

My code appears to pull the values of SpoilageQuantity and SpoilageUnitPrice OK, but fails at setting the value of SpoilageTotalPrice.  The error says that I'm trying to assign a value to a function result, but my understanding is that val() can be used to get and set a form field value.  Corrections or suggestions?

VS2010 view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SpoilageQuantity)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SpoilageQuantity)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SpoilageQuantity)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SpoilageUnitPrice)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SpoilageUnitPrice)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SpoilageUnitPrice)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SpoilageTotalPrice)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SpoilageTotalPrice)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SpoilageTotalPrice)
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
</div>
```

JS file:

```
function calculateTotal() {
// calculate total spoilage price from unit price and quantity
var totalprice = $('#SpoilageQuantity').val() * $('#SpoilageUnitPrice').val();
totalprice = totalprice.toFixed(2);

$('#SpoilageTotalPrice').val(totalprice);
}
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        <label for="SpoilageQuantity">Item Quantity</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Item Quantity must be a number." data-val-required="Quantity of item lost is required." id="SpoilageQuantity" name="SpoilageQuantity" type="text" value="0.00" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SpoilageQuantity" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="SpoilageUnitPrice">Unit Price</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Unit Price must be a number." data-val-required="Unit price is required." id="SpoilageUnitPrice" name="SpoilageUnitPrice" type="text" value="0.00" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SpoilageUnitPrice" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="SpoilageTotalPrice">Total Price</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Total Price must be a number." data-val-required="The Total Price field is required." id="SpoilageTotalPrice" name="SpoilageTotalPrice" type="text" value="0.00" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SpoilageTotalPrice" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    </div>
```

Error Message:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Cannot assign to a function result
```

Edit: Entire js file:

```
/*  Copyright 2012 Tom Barrett

This file is part of PFC Logs.

PFC Logs is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

PFC Logs is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with PFC Logs.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

function autoFocus() {
    // Auto-focus on the first text field upon page load.
    $("input[type=text]").first().focus();
}

function calculateTotal() {
    // calculate total from quantity & unit price
    var totalprice = $('#SpoilageQuantity').val() * $('#SpoilageUnitPrice').val();
    totalprice = totalprice.toFixed(2);
    $("#SpoilageTotalPrice").val(totalprice);
}
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that you're getting that error in that "calculateTotal()" function? Are you using the IE developer tools to step through the code?

Comment: You're using `val()` correctly and I can't see any problem with what you've posted.

Comment: Return false at the end of the function?

Comment: I think the problem is in my .js file, I probably have the syntax wrong somehow.  When I move the function to the page, everything works fine.  Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?  Added the contents of the js file above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the technicalities... but I've also come across this. If my functions are in a seperate js file which I link to within my  tags jquery (or Jscript for that matter) cannot find the elements. If I include the script within  tags all works well.